# Testing for Logical Equivalence

Tags: logic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quantifies, predicates, logical equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290646/quantifies-predicates-logical-equivalence)

I'm not looking just for an answer per say, but am also wondering the thought process in solving problems such as the following:

Hopefully this doesn't take up too much of someones time.

Determine whether the following equations are logically equivalent:

1) (∃x)( P(x) → Q(x) )

2) (∀x)P(x) → (∃x)Q(x)